# How to iterate through a table from last row to first?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table:

```
-----------------------
| id:      | data:    |
|---------------------|
| 1        | a        |
| 20       | b        |
| 546      | c        |
-----------------------
```

I want to store the data in an array from last inserted row (id is auto incremented) to first.

```
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM mytable');
$data = array();
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
return $data;
```

What can I add to the query in order to loop through the table from bottom to top?
I tried variations of `ORDER BY` but they didn't work, I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you try:  `order by id desc`?

Comment: select * from mytable order by id desc;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change MySQL statement to be

```
SELECT * FROM 'mytable' ORDER BY 'id' DESC
```

or reverse the array using PHPs reverse array function

```
return array_reverse($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Get records by descending order

use following query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable order by id desc
```

where id is the auto increment id of your table